# I can't set the height of my container after some limit

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(HomePage());

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home"),
        ),
        body: GridView(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: [
                              Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "ljsdgnvsdnv",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "sljdvnldnvsdb",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          height: 60,
                          width: 600,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print("Buton");
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can't set the height of my containers after some limit(also the widht of the second container), it doesn't give any errors but at the same time it doesn't change it's height. In flutter inspector their height and widht values are the values which are I assigned but it doesn't look like it. What should I do? (Text are random)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and didn't find any error while running it. But if the error that you are talking about are linked with the size of the container and some limit that you have added, than it's because you are trying to create an widget bigger than the zone that contain the widget.
You should check the limit that you have by trying:

```
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
```

And than you could give value that are within the zone.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the thing we missed was grid delegate takes an argument childAspectRatio which does the work we are trying to do. Thank you for your time.